# Get particular element from XML from URL Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, parsing

I'm trying to get a particular element in an XML file from a URL using an ElementTree. I am trying to get precipitation amount based on a certain date.

I can iterate through precipitation and time separately but I don't know how to get precipitation based on time.

XML File:

```
    <weatherdata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/schema" created="2019-10-24T15:20:55Z">
<meta>
<model name="harmonie" termin="2019-10-24T06:00:00Z" runended="2019-10-24T09:33:12Z" nextrun="2019-10-24T16:00:00Z" from="2019-10-24T16:00:00Z" to="2019-10-26T12:00:00Z"/>
<model name="ec_n1280_1hr" termin="2019-10-24T00:00:00Z" runended="2019-10-24T09:33:12Z" nextrun="2019-10-24T18:00:00Z" from="2019-10-26T13:00:00Z" to="2019-10-27T18:00:00Z"/>
<model name="ec_n1280_3hr" termin="2019-10-24T00:00:00Z" runended="2019-10-24T09:33:12Z" nextrun="2019-10-24T18:00:00Z" from="2019-10-27T21:00:00Z" to="2019-10-30T00:00:00Z"/>
<model name="ec_n1280_6hr" termin="2019-10-24T00:00:00Z" runended="2019-10-24T09:33:12Z" nextrun="2019-10-24T18:00:00Z" from="2019-10-30T06:00:00Z" to="2019-11-03T00:00:00Z"/>
</meta>
<product class="pointData">
<time datatype="forecast" from="2019-10-24T16:00:00Z" to="2019-10-24T16:00:00Z">
<location altitude="41" latitude="53.3639" longitude="-6.3333">
<temperature id="TTT" unit="celsius" value="9.8"/>
<windDirection id="dd" deg="327.6" name="NW"/>
<windSpeed id="ff" mps="4.4" beaufort="3" name="Lett bris"/>
<humidity value="87.2" unit="percent"/>
<pressure id="pr" unit="hPa" value="1004.5"/>
<cloudiness id="NN" percent="94.9"/>
<lowClouds id="LOW" percent="84.4"/>
<mediumClouds id="MEDIUM" percent="64.1"/>
<highClouds id="HIGH" percent="0.0"/>
<dewpointTemperature id="TD" unit="celsius" value="7.8"/>
</location>
</time>
<time datatype="forecast" from="2019-10-24T15:00:00Z" to="2019-10-24T16:00:00Z">
<location altitude="41" latitude="53.3639" longitude="-6.3333">
<precipitation unit="mm" value="1.0" minvalue="0.5" maxvalue="1.3"/>
<symbol id="Rain" number="10"/>
</location>
</time>
<time datatype="forecast" from="2019-10-24T17:00:00Z" to="2019-10-24T17:00:00Z">
<location altitude="41" latitude="53.3639" longitude="-6.3333">
<temperature id="TTT" unit="celsius" value="8.7"/>
<windDirection id="dd" deg="323.1" name="NW"/>
<windSpeed id="ff" mps="2.4" beaufort="2" name="Svak vind"/>
<humidity value="85.3" unit="percent"/>
<pressure id="pr" unit="hPa" value="1005.1"/>
<cloudiness id="NN" percent="96.3"/>
<lowClouds id="LOW" percent="90.1"/>
<mediumClouds id="MEDIUM" percent="61.7"/>
<highClouds id="HIGH" percent="0.0"/>
<dewpointTemperature id="TD" unit="celsius" value="6.3"/>
</location>
</time>
<time datatype="forecast" from="2019-10-24T16:00:00Z" to="2019-10-24T17:00:00Z">
<location altitude="41" latitude="53.3639" longitude="-6.3333">
<precipitation unit="mm" value="0.2" minvalue="0.0" maxvalue="0.5"/>
<symbol id="Drizzle" number="46"/>
</location>
</time>



for precip in xroot.iter('precipitation'):
     print(precip.attrib)
```

I want to be able to access precipitation based on

```
<time datatype="forecast" from="2019-10-24T15:00:00Z" to="2019-10-    24T16:00:00Z">
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
html = '''your xml'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# If you know the from or to time, just do this
# t = doc.selects('time@from="2019-10-24T16:00:00Z"')
# print (t.select('precipitation>value()'))
# else
searchTime = utils.convertStr2Time('2019-10-24T16:00:00Z',format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
times = doc.selects('time')
for t in times:
  fromTime = utils.convertStr2Time(t["from"],format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
  toTime = utils.convertStr2Time(t["to"],format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
  if searchTime>=fromTime and searchTime<=toTime:
    print (t.select('precipitation>value()'))
```

Result:

```
None
1.0
0.2
```